# Does one have to honor parents who’re in Nidui or Cherem

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, cherem, masechet-moed-katan, nidui-ostracism

In the Talmud, [the Gemara of tractate Moed Katan](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.14b.11) it rules that one still observes the laws of ostracism which supersede the commandment to rejoice on festivals. My question is, is the positive commandant to honor parents overridden by the practices of ostracism? So If one’s parents are put in Nidui or Cherem, are they still obligated to honor them or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the answer is yes. This can be seen from the gemara in Sanhedrin 68 where Hyrkanus is withing 4 amos of his father Eliezer who was in nidui(there to help remove teffilin ) ,and the talmidim kept a distance of 4 Amos. Indeed ,the Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 334:2 paskens that someone who is put into nidui cannot have anyone within their 4 amos except for his wife and children.